# Get the top 10 rows only

Tags: sql, sql-server

i want to get only the first 10 records from this select statement

```
SELECT SUM([Order].[Quantity]) As Quantity , [Order].ProductSKU_FK 
FROM [Order]
WHERE [Order].[Status] !='Fulfilled' 
GROUP BY [Order].[ProductSKU_FK] 
ORDER BY Quantity DESC;
```

Comment: You need to use TOP. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/top-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `TOP`?

```
SELECT TOP 10
    SUM([Quantity]) As Quantity,
    ProductSKU_FK
FROM [Order]
WHERE [Status] != 'Fulfilled'
GROUP BY ProductSKU_FK
ORDER BY Quantity DESC;
```